# Shifting eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a way to **shift** a specific eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ without changing any of its eigenvectors? In other words, can I find some $\Delta A$ such that $B = A + \Delta A$ that has the almost the same eigensystem except at 1 eigenvalue?

I understand that I can shift or scale all the eigenvalues at once, but not a particular one. Brauer's theorem (below) is the closest thing I find to what I need. However, although the eigenvector corresponding with $\lambda_0$ is not changed, it is not guaranteed that the remaining eigenvectors stay the same.

Any reference/suggestions are much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. Use your Theorem 1.1, but take $r=v$ and set $\Delta A = \delta vv^T$. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A+\Delta A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda+\delta$. The other eigenvectors of $A$ are orthogonal to $v$, so their eigenspaces are unchanged.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer that only works if $A$ is symmetric (or normal)

Comment: Thank you both so much! My matrix A is indeed symmetric, but I really appreciate Omnomnomnom's general solution!

Answer (score 3):

I'll consider just the case in which $A$ is diagonalizable.  A similar analysis applies in general.

There is a precise choice of $r$ that will not shift the other eigenvectors.  In particular: we have $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$ where $P$ is the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues.  Suppose that our eigenvector is the $i$th eigenvector in the columns of $P$, and take $e_i$ to be the $i$th column of the identity matrix.  It suffices to take
$$
\hat A = A + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_0)P(e_ie_i^T)P^{-1} = 
A + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_0)(Pe_i)(e_i^TP^{-1}) = 
A + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_0)vr^T
$$
where $r^T$ is the $i$th row of $P^{-1}$.  In the case that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, this is the **only** valid choice of $r$.